An Indian movie about a man with wolves/dogs
I am trying to remember an Indian movie I saw when I was kid.
It is about a man (the hero), who has long hair and a muscled body. He has a lot of dogs or wolves, about 5/6 of them. (they look like wolves, but I can't be sure). 
In the last scenes of the movie the hero runs beside a train which the bad guy is on, and he goes faster than the train. The train blows up and the hero gets out of the fire.
I think that the actor that plays the hero is a famous Bollywood star.
Does anyone know the name of the movie?

When did you watched it?

from 6 or 7 years

Could it been one of takes on Jungle Book and Mowgli character?

@VladimirOselsky I was thinking the same thing

@pipo anythingelse you remember ??

Could be this one The Second Jungle Book: Mowgli & Baloo (1997) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120087/

Jungle book is an American film and even animated. Not matching with required details.

@AnkitSharma, if you actually took the time to look it up on the imdb link I posted, you would realize this specific film  is NOT animated.

Oops......didn't noticed that. It doesn't have famous bollywood star as main lead but Gulshan Grover is surely a famous bollywood actor which might made OP confusing it with  bollywood film. +1. It's better to add a bit more detail to the answer.

@Jarnal - Rather than get all snarky over a misperception, maybe you could add some of that detail to your answer which would make it much better than just providing a title and a link. Maybe explain why it fits the question to start?
